Can one make a jet of air bounce without spreading?
Similar to this reaction on this image (left most) how it keeps its mass without spreading:

 (Video Link)
Is there a way to make a jet of air bounce without spreading?

(source)

Can one make a laminar flow region that does not transfer momentum and energy at its boundaries? Not in a real fluid.

The water in the video exists as droplets that are held together by their surface tension. After a droplet hits the hydrophobic surface and is flattened out by the impact, it's the surface tension, wanting to pull it back into a spherical shape, that provides the restoring force that makes the droplet bounce back up. Surface tension is a phenomenon that occurs at the boundary between the water and the air.
The air exiting from the leaf blower is a continuous stream. There are no droplets, there is no boundary between air and air, there is no surface tension. There is no restoring force that could make parcels of air "bounce."
